# Is there a way to set a Moq Mock to inhibate all of the void methods?

Tags: .net, moq

As stated, I would like to use a Mock where all of the void methods are inhibited.

I am mocking a CLASS and not an interface.
The default behaviour is to run the class methods.

```
MyClass = new Mock<MyClass>().Object;
```

Obviously, I can setup all of the methods to do nothing:

```
mock.Setup(p => p.MyMethod1(It.IsAny<string>()));
mock.Setup(p => p.MyMethod2(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

etc...

But maybe there is a special behaviour that does it without I need to do anything?

EDIT:
nothing particular about the class / methods themselves AFAIK.

```
public class MyClass
{
...
 public void MyMT(int p1, int? p2...)
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

The method calls I would like to "short-circuit" are as follows:

```
myClassInstance.Mymt(p1, p2...);
```

If what I want is impossible to achieve, my other plan will be to create a class inheriting from MyClass and override the concerned methods so they won't do nothing in the child class. I just had the feeling that Moq could do this without a line of code in some of its modes.

Comment: What is *inhibate*? Do you mean **inhibit**? If so, what is your goal? A mock method doesn't need any specific setup, the default for a `void` method is to do nothing already.

Comment: Yes I meant inhibit sorry. So that the method does nothing.

Comment: Are you sure this is the default when mocking a CLASS (not an interface)?
In my case, the mock still runs the mocked class method.

Comment: Well, I cannot see from your small code excerpt that you're not mocking an interface. You should improve your question and add all the relevant details. What does the class look like that you're trying to mock?

Comment: Very true, I ll edit to add this.

Comment: You still didn't show the actual class. How many methods are there, what is their signature?

Comment: OK I ve added more code samples as per your suggestion.

Comment: I understand what you want. The methods that you want to mock need to be `virtual`, otherwise Moq cannot mock them and that doesn't seem to be the case, at least not in your current example.

Comment: @ewerspej That was it!! Thanks a ton. :)
If you post it as an aswer, I will flag it as THE correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moq can only create mocks for methods that are marked as `virtual`, which allows them to be overriden.

So, if you change the signature of your methods to `virtual`, then Moq will be able to default-mock them. There is no need to specify a setup for the void methods, if they are not supposed to do anything.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod1()
    {
        //...
    }

    public virtual void MyMethod2()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will allow the methods to be overridden by any other class that inherits from your class. It's a design choice you need to make.

Comment: THis is what I had forgotten to do, thk for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at documentation here: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior

By default MockBehavior.Loose doesn't require you to setup all the methods of a service, if you want it to throw exception, set MockBehavior.Strict for a service you are mocking.

Comment: Indeed, by default it does not throw an exception, but it does run the original class method. Not what I want.
I want the mock not to run any code from the original class in this case.

Comment: Mock doesn't change your class and also doesn't run the methods if they are mocked. If you want original class not to be run at all, consider using FakeMyClass implementation instead of MyClass implementation, if you are injecting it.

Comment: There is no Dependency Injection in this project.